# ADL for class in anonymous namespace

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, argument-dependent-lookup

Does anybody know why [the next piece of code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a04bf6e2091313d3) isn't compiled on Clang 4.0.1?

I have the next error:

> call to function 'operator<<' that is neither visible in the template
>   definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup

There is some file **test.cpp**

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


namespace Wrapper
{

template<typename T>
struct QuotedStringImpl
{
    T const& Value;

    explicit QuotedStringImpl(T const& value) :
        Value(value)
    {
    }
};

template<typename T>
inline std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& stream, QuotedStringImpl<T> const& rhs)
{
    return stream << rhs.Value;
}

template<>
inline std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& stream, QuotedStringImpl<std::string> const& rhs)
{
    return stream << '"' << rhs.Value << '"';
}

template<typename T>
inline QuotedStringImpl<T> QuotedString(T const& value)
{
    return QuotedStringImpl<T>(value);
}

template<typename T>
inline std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& stream, std::vector<T> const& value)
{
    stream << "[";
    std::copy(value.begin(), value.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(stream, ", "));
    stream << "]";

    return stream;
}

} // namespace Wrapper


namespace
{

struct Struct
{
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, Struct const&)
{
    return stream << "(struct value)";
}

} // namespace

int main()
{
    std::vector<Struct> collection(2);
    std::cout << Wrapper::QuotedString(collection);
}
```

This code is successfully compiled with msvc 15. But I have troubles with Clang 4.0.1. According with [this](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#dep_lookup) documentation ADL should be applied in place of instantiation. But it doesn't work for me. What is the reason of such behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<typename T>
inline std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& stream, std::vector<T> const& value)
{
    stream << "[";
    std::copy(value.begin(), value.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(stream, ", "));
    stream << "]";

    return stream;
}
```

this operator isn't in any associatied namespace of `vector` or `ostream` or `T` (which in this case is `anonymous_ns::Struct`).  So it cannot be found via ADL.

It is attempted to be called by:

```
template<typename T>
inline std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& stream, QuotedStringImpl<T> const& rhs)
{
    return stream << rhs.Value;
}
```

which is located *earlier* in the source.

As a general rule, adding operators outside of the namespace of a type is a bad plan.

As a specific rule, adding operators into `namespace std` is illegal.

As a consequence, adding operators to types or templates in `namespace std` is a bad plan.

To fix your specific problem, simply move the definition of the above `<<` above the point where it is called.  Your code now compiles.  It remains fragile, because it relies on adding operators to types from `std`.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/rWHCLM).

MSVC fails to do proper two-phase lookup, so it (in error) compiles your code.  Proper two-phase lookup does a lookup at the point where the template was defined, and then does an *ADL only* lookup at the point where it is instantiated.

MSVC instead does a *full* lookup at the point where it is instantiated.  This is in violation of the C++ standard.

Comment: You are right. Thank you!